# how to use default captcha to custom form in magento2

Tags: magento2, captcha

i have tried following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Kensium\Catalogrequest\Block\Catalogrequest" name="catalogrequest" template="Kensium_Catalogrequest::catalogrequest.phtml" >
                <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha\DefaultCaptcha" name="catalogreqcaptcha" />
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```